# $mail = new PHPMailer(true); statement is failing

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am troubleshooting a code I inherited, and code that includes PHPMailer stopped working earlier this week. Here is a stripped-down code version with echo statements inserted to see where it fails.

```
<?php

echo '<p>First Debug line<br></p>';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

echo '<p>after use<br></p>';

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo '<p>after vendor/autoload.php<br></p>';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

echo '<p>After PHPMailer<br></p>'; // this statement does not get executred
```

**REV 1.**
Added following error trapping and I get the following now. What is puzzling to me that it was working a couple of days ago...

First Debug line

after use

after vendor/autoload.php

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in...

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo '<p>First Debug line<br></p>';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

echo '<p>after use<br></p>';

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

echo '<p>after vendor/autoload.php<br></p>';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

echo '<p>After PHPMailer<br></p>';
```

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? What changed earlier in the week, PHP update/downgrade?

Comment: Not sure... How can I tell if it is? As I said - this is an application that I inherited.

Comment: please post the error for better identify the issue

Comment: The webpage does not show any errors. It displays the echo statements, but nothing else seems to be failing as far as I can tell

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display sounds like you do not have error reporting enabled.

Comment: @EgilsRobs add `ini_set("error_reporting", -1)` and `display_errors(true)` to the top of your script.

Comment: If you are using Gmail, they recently disabled `less-secure-apps`, which might be the reason your PHPMailer is not working. You will have to use an `app password` instead. Checkout this url: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-an-app-password

Comment: Fatal errors will appear in your web servers error log. The gmail change was a good guess this week, but it's not getting to the point where that would explain it.